# Component/Service, change detection and zone

Tags: angular

i'm actually in trouble with zone. I have a component, in a ngmodule called App, calling another component called "tache-list", from another ngmodule called "Dossier" (App imports Dossier).
I send a http request, with a TacheService, returning my taches (tasks), and i want to print them with my TacheListComponent. However, when page is loaded, there is no change detection. I made many researchs, and found some documentation about zone and Angular Zone. I tried to use NgZone.run(), and this time the taches changes are detected. 
How is that possible ? is there a better way than paste the run function in all my service functions ? Thank you for you respond, it seems that informations about angular zone are rare...

tache-list.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit }      from '@angular/core';
import { TacheService } from '../services/tache.service';
import { Tache } from '../entities/tache.ts';
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from "@angular/core";
import 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise'
@Component({ 
    selector: 'tache-list',
    templateUrl: 'build/dossier/partials/tache-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['build/dossier/css/tache-list.component.css']
})
export class TacheListComponent implements OnInit {
    title: String = 'Liste des tâches';
    taches: Object[];
    errorMessage: any;
    subscriptions: any[] = [];
    constructor(private tacheService: TacheService, private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getTachesDuJour();
    }
    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscriptions.forEach(sub => {
            sub.unsubscribe();
        });
    }

    getTachesDuJour() {
        return this.tacheService.getTachesDuJour().subscribe(
            taches => {
                this.taches = taches;
                //this.changeDetector.detectChanges(); 
            },
            error => {
                this.errorMessage = <any>error;
            }
        );
    }
}
```

tache.service.ts :

```
import { Injectable, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
@Injectable()
export class TacheService implements OnInit {
    url: string = 'http://web-pierre/ebexapplication/public/api/tache';

    constructor(private http: Http, private zone: NgZone) { }
    ngOnInit() {

    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body || {};
    }
    private handleError(error: any) {
        let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message : error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
        console.error(errMsg);
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }

    getTachesDuJour(): Observable<Object[]> {
        this.zone.run(() => {});
        var response = this.http.get(this.url).map(res => this.extractData(res)).catch(this.handleError);
        return response;
    } 
}
```

Comment: If you don't want it in your service function you could do it in the next handler of the subscribe instead. Are you doing this in web, desktop, or mobile?

Comment: In web. What do you mean by the next handler of the subscribe ? In my component ?

Comment: Yes, in your component. taches => this.zone.run(() => this.taches = taches);

Obserables have three functions you can provide to a subscription: onNext, onError, onComplete in that order. Here is a resource to review: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/subscribe.md

Comment: The code you show should work without needing to call `zone.run()`.  Are you using the `OnPush` change detection strategy somewhere in your app?  Can you reproduce the problem in a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/)?

Comment: Found the problem, I was loading in bad order the zone.js file. So dumb... Thanks for your answers

Comment: @Pythorogus please add that as an answer, or delete this question, so the question does not remain open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem, I was loading in bad order the zone.js file. So dumb... Thanks for your answers.